# Files Served from CDN are not Compressed

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, cdn, url-rewrite-module

Files Served from CDN are not showing compressed in Response Header although when I remove rule rewrite and the files directly served from IIS are gzipped.

Hi,

I have implemented CDN using outbound rule in my ASP.NET website and also enabled dynamic and static compression. But the problem is content served from CDN provider not showing content-encoding: gzip or any other compression method.

So my question is content served from CDN should be compressed from CDN provider or is there anything doable in IIS. My web.config code sample is give below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>             
                <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match filterByTags="Script" pattern="http(s)?://(www.mydomain.com)/js/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://cdn.com/js/{R:3}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                  
                    <preCondition name="IsHtml">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
            
        </rewrite> 
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
     </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your website Compression setting in IIS, something like this:

[image]

If it shows message "The dynamic content compression module is not installed" in Alerts, just go to the "Turn Windows features on or off" and select "Dynamic Content Compression" and click the OK button and finish installing this module.

Comment: Hi, Xudong Peng, thanks for the comment. I already have the Static and Dynamic compression installed in the server. I thought it could be from CDN provider as if I check files from cdn, then its like uncompressed but if i checked same file from my iis, then its compressed.

Comment: Well, I tested that too, and this setting works locally. As you said, the content-encoding header is not displayed should be caused by the server-side settings of the CDN provider, which is out of our control.